# Datatable updating without using datarow loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable

Is it possible to do the following:

I have the following datatable

```
=================================
ID      ||   Width  ||  Value  ||
=================================
size-1  ||   50     ||         ||
name-1  ||   100    ||         ||
zip-1   ||   50     ||         ||
size-2  ||   50     ||         ||
name-2  ||   100    ||         ||
zip-2   ||   50     ||         ||
=================================
```

I want to be able to loop through the datatable and update the value column, with the textcontrolbox.text value

```
Session[sectionName] = test;
DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session[sectionName];

        var strIDS = from p in dt.AsEnumerable()
                     select new
                     {
                         ID = p.Field<string>("ID")
                     };

        foreach (var strID in strIDS)
        {
            TextBox tempBox = DynamicControlsHolder1.FindControl(strID.ID) as TextBox;
            string val = tempBox.Text;

            // This is where i want to be able to update the value column, but i can't figure out how to
            // Can someone please help

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your entire code can be replaced by:

```
foreach (DataRow Row in dt.Rows)
    Row["Value"] = (DynamicControlsHolder1.FindControl(Row["ID"]) as TextBox).Text;
```

Comment: +1 for simple use of traditional `foreach`, in fact I prefer this style more than `LINQ`, `LINQ` is just for the OP's request. `LINQ` is not always the best but many people are always trying to use it as much as possible.

Comment: wow, i like that way, it seems a lot cleaner, but when i tried that now, it says that the findcontrol has some invalid arguments, and i had to add the following:   foreach(DataRow Row in dt.rows)

Comment: it worked, i just had to add the following for it to work: foreach (DataRow Row in dt.Rows)
        {
            Row["Value"] = (DynamicControlsHolder1.FindControl((string)Row["ID"]) as TextBox).Text;
        }

Comment: Ah, `foreach(DataRow r in dt)` would work fine with a Typed Dataset. I'll update my code.

Answer (score 3):

```
int i = 0;
foreach (var strID in strIDS)
    {
        TextBox tempBox = DynamicControlsHolder1.FindControl(strID.ID) as TextBox;
        dt.Rows[i++]["Value"] = tempBox.Text;
    }
```

I think you should try updating right in the `LINQ`, like this:

```
var totalRows = dt.AsEnumerable()                  
                  .Select(p=>                     
                  {
                     p["Value"] = (DynamicControlsHolder1.FindControl(p.Field<string>("ID")) as TextBox) ?? "";
                     return p;
                  }).Count();
```

To update a specific row, you can try this:

```
var row = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .Where(p=>p.Field<string>("ID") == "ID you want").FirstOrDefault();
if(row != null) row["Value"] = (DynamicControlsHolder1.FindControl(row["ID"].ToString()) as TextBox).Text;
```

Comment: -1. There's no guarantee that the rows are in order. He needs to find rows by ID.

Comment: AH, I see it now. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: What if needed to only update one specific row, is there a way to do that by using the findbyid, even though my datatable doesn't have a primary key?

Comment: @user2593590: See my answer below.